# Xamarin.Forms Sip: 'Internal server error 500' When Placing Outgoing Calls

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sip, linphone

I am using Linphone SDK in Xamarin.forms project for the sip calling. I am able to make the connection using following code:

```
           var authInfo = Factory.Instance.CreateAuthInfo(username.Text, 
           null, password.Text, null, null,domain.Text);
            LinphoneCore.AddAuthInfo(authInfo);
            String proxyAddress ="sip:"+username.Text+"@192.168.1.180:5160";
            var identity = Factory.Instance.CreateAddress(proxyAddress);
            var proxyConfig = LinphoneCore.CreateProxyConfig();
            identity.Username = username.Text;
            identity.Domain = domain.Text;
            identity.Transport = TransportType.Udp;
            proxyConfig.Edit();
            proxyConfig.IdentityAddress = identity;
            proxyConfig.ServerAddr = domain.Text + ":5160;transport=udp";
            proxyConfig.Route = domain.Text;
            proxyConfig.RegisterEnabled = true;

            proxyConfig.Done();

            LinphoneCore.AddProxyConfig(proxyConfig);
            LinphoneCore.DefaultProxyConfig = proxyConfig;

            LinphoneCore.RefreshRegisters();
```

After Successful connection, I am using the code for placing the code.

```
        if (LinphoneCore.CallsNb == 0)
        {
            string phoneCall = "sip:"+address.Text+ "@192.168.1.180:5160";
            var addr = LinphoneCore.InterpretUrl(phoneCall);
            LinphoneCore.InviteAddress(addr);
        }
        else
        {
            Call call = LinphoneCore.CurrentCall;
            if (call.State == CallState.IncomingReceived)
            {
                LinphoneCore.AcceptCall(call);
            }
            else
            {
                LinphoneCore.TerminateAllCalls();
            }
        }
```

And the listener that is listening to call state changed event is as:

```
   private void OnCall(Core lc, Call lcall, CallState state, stringmessage)
   {
        call_status.Text = "Call state changed: " + state;

        if (lc.CallsNb > 0)
        {
            if (state == CallState.IncomingReceived)
            {
                call.Text = "Answer Call (" + lcall.RemoteAddressAsString + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                call.Text = "Terminate Call";
            }
            if (lcall.CurrentParams.VideoEnabled) {
                video.Text = "Stop Video";
            } else {
                video.Text = "Start Video";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            call.Text = "Start Call";
            call_stats.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

The call status is giving 'Internal Server Error'. I am able to receive the calls using Linphone or X-lite Soft Phone in my code, But I am not able to place the calls. I don't know whether this issue is related to server or it is related to my code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**Internal Server Error** ([HTTP Status code 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors)) means that an unexpected error occurred on the server. So I would suspect the problem is rather there than with your app's code.

> **500** - A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.

It could be that your request doesn't satisfy the expectations of the endpoint you are calling, but even then, the server should then respond with a more meaningful error, than crashing with 500.